# Why am I having display problems with jinja2 and html?

Tags: html, jinja2

[image]I'm having a display problem. I have a chart I'm filling in with data. Except that when I have more than one data per row instead of the other data going to the row, they stay on the same row. For example, when I retrieve user mentions and there are 3 screen_names for a result, my output is: a b c
Except that a b c protrudes from the intended column and overflows into the following columns. I wish a, b, c were in the same column:
a \n
b \n
c \n
My code:

```
{% for item in res%}
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ item['_source']['lang'] }}</th>
      <td>{{ item['_source']['id'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['_source']['date'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['_source']['full_text']}}</td>
      <td>{{ item['_source']['user']['name']}}</td>
      <td>{{ item['_source']['user']['screen_name']}} </td>
      <td>{{ item['_source']['user']['location']}} </td>
      <td>{{ item['_source']['user']['id']}} </td>
      {% for i in item['_source']['entities']['user_mentions'] if i["screen_name"] %}
      <td>    {{ i["screen_name"] }} <td>
      {% else %}
       <td>   None <td>
      {% endfor %}
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your HTML. You are not closing your tags and you have a random {% else %} in the middle of your loop. From what I understand of your question you will want to format it like this:

```
{% for item in res %}
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ item['_source']['lang'] }}</th>
        <td>{{ item['_source']['id'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item['_source']['date'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item['_source']['full_text'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item['_source']['user']['name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item['_source']['user']['screen_name'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ item['_source']['user']['location'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ item['_source']['user']['id'] }} </td>

        <td>
            {% for i in item['_source']['entities']['user_mentions'] if i["screen_name"] %}
                {{ i["screen_name"] }}<br>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```